# Apache Lucene Effective searching way

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am new to Apache Lucene. I'm Trying to provide effective simple search code using Apache Lucene. Searching word through many text files.I want to get this word position through each text file and word before it,and after.I want fast method.Here is my code it can't recognize the word before/after found results.Thanks in advance.Also this code is good ? talking about efficiency.

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.*;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyQuery;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    indexDirectory();

    String userInput = "";
    Scanner getInputWord = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please type a word to search for.\nInput: ");
    userInput = getInputWord.next();
    search(userInput);

    System.out.print("Search again? (type Y or N) Y = Yes, N = No: ");
    userInput = getInputWord.next();
    while (!userInput.equals("n") && !userInput.equals("N")) {
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        userInput = getInputWord.next();
        search(userInput);
        System.out.print("Search again? (Y or N): ");
        userInput = getInputWord.next();
    }
}

private static void indexDirectory() {
    // Apache Lucene Indexing Directory .txt files
    try {
        Path path;
        path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Yasser\\Desktop\\index");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);

        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
        indexWriter.deleteAll();
        File f = new File("C:\\seminar\\test_data"); // current directory
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            // System.out.println("indexed " + file.getCanonicalPath());
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new TextField("FileName", file.getName(), Store.YES));

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            doc.add(new TextField("contents", stringBuffer.toString(), Store.YES));
            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
        }
        indexWriter.close();
        directory.close();
        System.out.println("indexing finished");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void search(String text) {
    // Apache Lucene searching text inside .txt files
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\yasser\\Desktop\\index");

        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
        IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        FuzzyQuery query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("contents", text), 2);
        TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 10);
        int i = 0;
        if (topDocs.totalHits > 0) {
            System.out.println("Found " + topDocs.totalHits + " result(s).");
            for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
                Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                i = i + 1;
                System.out.println("Result #" + i + " " + document.get("FileName"));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No maches found!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do? Give an example input file with a few words in it, and write what you would expect the output to be.

Comment: supposed to provide  user input word eg"book", this word will be found in many texts . above code will print results  number, and text files name contain that word.This is great. But want to improve code to  get that word book in each text file position and if its repeated in that text.I know tradition methods. but this will take much time for searching.I want very fast way to handle this job.Also that cod above is good or bad. can I  improve it to be much faster.
code job is to search word through many text files exist in provided path